# Regex match on redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am having little trouble with regex on redshift. The regex works fine when i use it in my scala code but does not works on redshift. I understand that the syntax might be somewhat different in redshift. Can anyone help me out here.

regex: `(^VISA\s*MONEY\s*TRANSFER\s*.*\s*CASH\s*APP\**\s*.*Visa Direct CA.*\s*)`

in redshift:

```
select *
from table where column ~ '(^VISA\s*MONEY\s*TRANSFER\s*.*\s*CASH\s*APP\**\s*.*Visa Direct CA.*\s*)' limit 2;
```

Err:

> ERROR: XX000: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition
>   operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression
>   fragment: 'ASHs*APP**>>>HERE>>>s*.*Visa D'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is the `'APP\**'` part: since you did not use a literal backslash, but an escape symbol, in front of a non-expected second char of a string escape sequence, the backslash got removed by the engine, and the resulting `APP**` pattern caused an exception, since a quantifier itself cannot be quantified.

You may use

```
select * from table where column ~ '^VISA\\s*MONEY\\s*TRANSFER.*CASH\\s*APP.*Visa Direct CA.*' limit 2;
```

I removed some redundant patterns, and escaped backslashes properly. To enter a literal backslash, you need to double it in a string literal.

Comment: Thank  Wiktor. that worked. Also I went through the aws documentation here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html